# Binding<Bool> to Binding<Bool?> in Swift

Tags: swiftui

`NavigationLink`s `selected` parameeter takes in Binding but my `ObservedObject` has Bool variable not an Optional value.
How to convert it so that selected would accept it?

Code:

```
class RegistrationFlowEnvironment: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var done = false
}
```

the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var regFlowEnv = RegistrationFlowEnvironment()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink("Go to other place", destination: Dest(),
                               tag: true,
                               selection: $regFlowEnv.done)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fixed variant (tested with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7)

```
NavigationView {
    VStack{
        NavigationLink("Go to other place", destination: Text("Dest"),
                       tag: true,
                       selection: Binding($regFlowEnv.done))
    }
}
```